# How to install xapk in a android mobile?

Tags: java, android

What is the difference between apk and xapk ??  and why xapk can't install in mobile ?? I download it from internet in computer and want to install in a mobile , but it can't install in a mobile

Comment: You may find this link helpful . https://apkpure.com/xapk.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.xapk file is a standard zip file which contains a .apk file and a .OBB file (contains additional application data like graphics and application assets). These type of files are used to distribute android applications on third party android application download websites (Just like the .apk files are published on Google Play Store). These are a way around to tackle size limitations in most cases.

To install a .xapk file on your device do the following:

1) Extract the .xapk file and you will get a .apk file and a .OBB file.

2) Place the .OBB file in the relevant folder (Application folder).

3) Run the .apk file.

You can also use utilities known as .xapk installers if you don't want to do it manually.

Comment: See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/234797/327095) for detailed instructions.